# Model def in View State

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my ruby on rails project
in model, I have some of definition.

```
class PlaySport < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :sport

  def self.getLevel
  end  

  def self.check_play_sport(cuser_id,sport_id)
  end  

  def current_playing_sports
  end

  def all_played_sports
  end

end
```

I catch for this relation like this

```
current_user.play_sports.current_playing_sports
```

But I get the undefined method error "current_playing_sports"

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#current_playing_sport` is a method on an instance of a PlaySport model. `current_user.play_sports` will (judging by the naming) return an array of PlaySport instances. So, you'd want to iterate through them and invoke `#current_playing_sport` on each.

Answer (score 0):

play_sports is an association so you can not call instance methods defined inside PlaySport model.

play_sports will return collection so you can call the method using map or each like

```
current_user.play_sports.map &:current_playing_sports
```

also do remember this will again return array which will have result of current_playing_sports method for each PlaySport model.

Comment: how i display this in view state ? <%current_user.play_sports.map &:current_playing_sports %> ??

Comment: I think there is something missing, what you want to achieve? Displaying one or many current sport playing by an user? what is the name of attribute in play_sport which needs to be displayed?

Comment: yes.by default : user can be 3 play sports ( like current playing sport ). but user has many sport . he can change sport .so user have more than 3 sport . for this we diff two def : current_palying_sport & all_played_sport

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are trying to invoke the method current_playing_sports on an array of play_sport objects.

You need to invoke the method on each of the play_sport objects,

Something like,

current_user.play_sports.collect(&:current_playing_sports)

My doubt,

You have defined a method called "current_playing_sport" and you are trying to access "current_playing_sports". I guess you need to fix the typo

You need to define a has_many relationship.

In your model, add this.

```
has_many :current_playing_sports
```

this should solve all your issues.

Comment: how i display this in view state ? <%current_user.play_sports.collect( &:current_playing_sports).each do |sp| %> xxxxxx <%end%> ? Pls....

Comment: yes this is correct, But then you don't seem to be having a method called "current_playing_sports". What you have is a method called "current_playing_sport"

Comment: in for each I do : <%=sp.id %><%=sp.sport_name%> . But it return undefined method id , sport_name